# Java Method Refactoring Using Enum

Tags: java

The getCategory method below seems very redundant and I was wondering if anyone has some suggestions on refactoring it to make it cleaner possibly using an Enum.  Based on the "val" passed in, I need getCategory to return the proper Category instance from the Category class.  The Category class is generated JNI code, so I don't want to change that.  Anyone have any ideas?

**Method to be refactored:**

```
private Category getCategory(String val) throws Exception{
        Category category;
        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("producer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER;
        } else if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("meter")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_METER;
        } else if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("consumer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value: " + val);
        }       
        return usageCategory;
    }
```

**Category.java: Generated JNI (can't change this):**

```
public final class Category {
  public final static Category CATEGORY_PRODUCER = new Category("CATEGORY_PRODUCER", SampleJNI.CATEGORY_PRODUCER_get());
  public final static Category CATEGORY_METER = new Category("CATEGORY_METER", SampleJNI.CATEGORY_METER_get());
  public final static Category CATEGORY_CONSUMER = new Category("CATEGORY_CONSUMER", SampleJNI.CATEGORY_CONSUMER_get());

}
```

Comment: IMO, your method is pretty clean right now, it's a simple factory method. Unless you need method like this in many other classes, I will not suggest you spend time to improve this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is essentially *mapping* from a predetermined `String` to a `Category`, so why not use a `Map` instead? Specifically, I'd recommend Guava's [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html), since these mappings are static:

```
private static final ImmutableMap<String, Category> CATEGORIES_BY_STRING =
        ImmutableMap.of(
            "producer", Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER,
            "meter", Category. CATEGORY_METER,
            "consumer", Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER
        );
```

Or the standard way if you don't want to use a third-party library:

```
private static final Map<String, Category> CATEGORIES_BY_STRING;
static {
    Map<String, Category> backingMap = new HashMap<String, Category>();
    backingMap.put("producer", Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER);
    backingMap.put("meter", Category.CATEGORY_METER);
    backingMap.put("producer", Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER);
    CATEGORIES_BY_STRING = Collections.unmodifiableMap(backingMap);
}
```

You could still employ your method to check for invalid values (and support case-insensitivity as David Harkness pointed out):

```
private Category getCategory(String val) {
    Category category = CATEGORIES_BY_STRING.get(val.toLowerCase());
    if (category == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return category;
}
```

---

**About using enums:**

If you have complete control over the `String`s that are passed into `getCategory`, and would only be passing literal values, then it does make sense to switch to an `enum` instead.

**EDIT:** Previously, I recommended using an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) for this case, but [Adrian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022765/697449) makes much more sense.

Comment: `getCategory` is case-insensitive. Does the above use of `ImmutableMap` address this?

Comment: @Paul Bellora - I like your suggestion but I'm looking for a solution that uses java 1.6.  I believe I would have to add another library to implement this, correct?

Comment: @DavidHarkness - Of course, you're right - so the method is still needed, see my edit.

Comment: @DavidHarkness make getCategory()  always lowercase the input value before CATEGORIES_BY_STRING.get() should be no problem

Answer (score 5):

If you said you want to refactor base on enum, I assume you mean you no longer want to pass in the String to getCategory to do all those work.  The code is using enum directly, instead of using String.

If this is the case, continue reading

Luckily, your Category is static variables, so you can do something real straight-forward

```
public enum FooCategory {  // give a better name yourself
  PRODUCER(Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER),
  METER(Category.CATEGORY_METER),
  CONSUMER(Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER)

  private Category category;
  FooCategory(Category category) {
    this.category=category;
  }
  Category getCategory() {
    return this.category;
  }
}
```

In your old code, you are doing something like:

```
String fooCategory = "producer";
//....
Category category = getCategory(fooCategory);
// work on category
```

Now you are doing something much neater

```
FooCategory fooCategory = FooCategory.PRODUCER;
//...
Category category = fooCategory.getCategory();
// work on category
```

Comment: +1 This actually makes more sense than my answer about using enums.

Comment: @Adrian Shum - I still need to make decisions based on a String passed (i.e. "producer", "consumer"..etc).  So if I'm reading your answer correctly, I would still have the if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("producer") switch logic, correct?

Comment: @c12 - Using an enum instead of string literals is definitely recommended if possible - but if you're forced to base decisions on a `String` being passed, you would need to stick to the `Map` solution.

Comment: @c12 - as PaulBellora suggested, you should avoid using string literal.  If for some reason you still need, apart from the most optimal Map solution, you still have an alternative: add a member var in FooCategory storing the string representation, and iterate FooCateory.values() to do string comparisons.  Only use it if the value of the enum is minimal (below 5 I will say).

Comment: @AdrianShum - to make sure I understand, I have a lot of IF statements that test specific values that drive my business logic in other spots of code, i.e. if(val.equalsIgnoreCase("abc"){ dothis();}else if{val.equalsIgnoreCase("def"){dosomethingelse();}...etc.  I should use an Enum for "abc", "def"..etc?  Does this have performance impact?

Comment: @c12 it is hard to tell coz we have no idea on your design.  You should know whether it is a good candidate to use enum.  At least in your example here, it seems appropriate to use.  For performance impact, yes, there will surely be.  Using enum will surely run faster than doing string comparison.  :)  And most importantly, it is less error-prone, easier to read, and give a clearer semantic meaning

Answer (score 1):

@PaulBellora and @AdrianShum 's answers are both great, but I think you can't avoid using magic value just like 'producer'(case-insensitive) to produce `Category` for storage reason. So I'm afraid the redundant code in `getCategory` can't avoid either. (Unfortunately, the magic values used to init `Category` and get `Category` are not same)

Here are the code to use `Enum`(Java 1.5 or above):

```
public enum Category {
    CATEGORY_PRODUCER,
    CATEGORY_METER,
    CATEGORY_CONSUMER;

    public static Category of(String val) throws Exception {
        Category usageCategory;
        if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("producer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER;
        } else if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("meter")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_METER;
        } else if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("consumer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value: " + val);
        }       
        return usageCategory;
    }
}
```

If you use the same magic value to produce, fetch and store, you can:

```
public enum Category {
    CATEGORY_PRODUCER("producer"),
    CATEGORY_METER("meter"),
    CATEGORY_CONSUMER("consumer");

    private String category;
    private Category(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public static Category of(String val) throws Exception {
        Category usageCategory;
        // You can use equals not equalsIgnoreCase, so you can use map to avoid redundant code.
        // Because you use the same magic value everywhere.
        if (val.equals("producer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_PRODUCER;
        } else if (val.equals("meter")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_METER;
        } else if (val.equals("consumer")) {
            usageCategory = Category.CATEGORY_CONSUMER;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Invalid value: " + val);
        }       
        return usageCategory;
    }
}
```

and create a `Category` as:

```
Category category = Category.of("producer");
```

Of course, you have to change the code to include `SampleJNI.CATEGORY_CONSUMER_get()`.